# Check if prompt only contains numbers and commas

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have a prompt in JS: `var ask = prompt("What content do you want to link?");`

I only want `ask` to contain numbers and commas. For example, an example input might be: `5,3,1`

I know you can't do this *during* the prompt, but I want to validate the information *after* the prompt. So:

```
if(ask only contains numbers and commas) {
alert("True!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use `regex` like below, which matches a `number` or `numbers separated by commas`

```js
var ask = prompt("What content do you want to link?");
if (ask) {
  if (ask.match(/^[0-9]+[(,)(0-9)]*[0-9]+$/))
    alert("correct format")
  else
    alert("wrong format")
}
```